# How to write a linq statement that parses and checks value of a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IList<string>` that has values like this:

```
string[] tags = {"firstValue:1","secondValue:5", "thirdValue:10"}
```

is there an easy way I can write a Linq statement without looping through each value?

This is what I have so far:

```
var secondValue = tags.FirstOrDefault(tag => tag.Split(':')[0] == "secondValue");
var answer = secondValue.Split(':')[1];
```

while this works, I'd like a more concise way where I don't have to split the string twice

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: Perhaps you can convert List to a Dictionary ?

Comment: I wanted a more concise way instead of having to split twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have got the answer yourself, you can join them together like this:

```
var answer = tags.FirstOrDefault(tag => tag.Split(':')[0] == "secondValue").Split(':')[0];
```

in your case you can skip the first split like:

```
var answer = tags.FirstOrDefault(tag => tag.StartsWith("secondValue:")).Split(':')[0];
```

For null checking simply do:

```
var answer = tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.StartsWith("secondValue:"))?.Split(':')[1] ?? "0";
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Ti2gT)

Comment: yes, that seems more concise. Is there a way I could also do null checks in case it doesn't exsit in the list?

Comment: @RDoolabh yes of course. please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go dictionary route (which is prefereable if you use a list few times), there's no need to split twice:

```
static void  Main(string[] args)
{
    var tags =new List<string> { "firstValue:1", "secondValue:5", "thirdValue:10" };
    var dict= tags.Select(s => s.Split(':')).ToDictionary(ss => ss[0], ss => ss[1]);
    var sec = dict["secondValue"];
    Console.WriteLine(sec);
    var exists = dict.Keys.Contains("nonexist");
    Console.WriteLine(exists);
    if (!dict.TryGetValue("nonexist", out string nonexistValue))
            nonexistValue = "99";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(nonexistValue);
}
```